# ABRT problem (killed by SIGABRT)

Tags: abrt

I have webmin/virtualmin install on centos7 server. Does anyone know why I'm getting this ABRT problem? Also, how do I prevent this from happening.

ABRT has detected 2 problem(s). For more info run: abrt-cli list --since 1659022602
[root@mail ~]# abrt-cli list --since 1659022602
id ca222c42101aa4916ca8650854c207c97e707387
reason:         systemd-journald killed by SIGABRT
time:           Tue 26 Jul 2022 09:11:46 PM CEST
cmdline:        /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journald
package:        systemd-219-78.el7_9.5
uid:            0 (root)
count:          3
Directory:      /var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2022-07-26-21:11:46-400

id c4bee002dea451ab58154e5313cad41fcf2d08a1
reason:         systemd-journald killed by SIGABRT
time:           Tue 26 Jul 2022 09:58:50 PM CEST
cmdline:        /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journald
package:        systemd-219-78.el7_9.5
uid:            0 (root)
count:          3
Directory:      /var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2022-07-26-21:58:49-9109

Comment: Someone with more patience might know more, but I simply uninstalled all the abort packages.

Comment: thanks! I'll give that a shot.